# Scala: Using companion object's parent's protected methods

Tags: scala

I have a set of classes that manage db storage in a class hierarchy as outlined below, and would like for the case class to be able to access the protected methods in the companion object's parent class:

```
class TableBase[T] { 
  protected def insert(...):T {...}
  protected def update(...) {...}
  // Other "raw" CRUD-methods that I don't want the 
  // world to have access to
}

object User extends TableBase[User] { 
}

case class User(id:Int, email:String) { 
  // But here it would be really useful to access the "raw" CRUD methods:
  def changeEmail(newEmail:String) = User.update(...)
}
```

Only problem is that the call to User.update in User.changeEmail is illegal since User (class) is not in the inheritance chain from TableBase:

```
method update in class TableBase cannot be accessed in object models.User 
Access to protected method update not permitted because enclosing class 
class User in package models is not a subclass of class TableBase in package 
models where target is defined
```

Is there a (convenient) way to allow for this type of calling?

Right now I have to either move the changeEmail-type functions into the singleton, which makes the calling code rather verbose, or duplicate the method signatures.

Comment: Is declaring the methods [`private` or `protected` at the package-level](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/packages-and-imports.html#lst:access-qualifiers) an option?

Comment: In theory, yes. It would require quite a bit of rejigging - TableBase is in a separate, symlink-source-shared project, used by several other projects, so mangling the package space would be a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that a possible solution is to switch the "is-a" to a "has-a" relationship between User and TableBase, like so:

```
class TableBase[T] { 
  def insert(...):T {...}
  def update(...) {...}
}

object User { 
  private val db = new TableBase[User]
}

case class User(id:Int, email:String) { 
  def changeEmail(newEmail:String) = User.db.update(...)
}
```

I wanted to be able to customize some aspects of TableBase inside User, but that's actually still possible and quite easy by doing:

```
object User { 
  private val db = new TableBase[User] { 
    // Override stuff here
  }
}
```

Actually, that's a much better solution than what I originally had and avoids naming conflicts on the methods (i.e. there's reason to have a public "insert" on User and it's nice to not have it result in partly protected overloading).

Comment: I tried this out and was unhappy with the result - in the end it was somewhat arbitrary what functionality was going to go into TableBase (and thereby be hidden) and what was going to be externally accessible. Ended up just letting the TableBase contents be public. In a more clear-cut scenario this is the approach I would take though.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the interface as a trait CrudOps[T], have another *protected* trait TableBase[T] derive from it and provide the implementation, and derive the singleton object from TableBase[T]. This way TableBase is not visible outside the compilation unit, but clients can safely consume CrudOps[T].

Comment: I'm probably missing something - I want the methods in TableBase/CrudOps to only be callable inside the User class & singleton, not externally - if clients can "consume" CrudOps, then update/insert/etc are externally callable?

(note that the files are not actually in the same package or source file)

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes it easier - just make the TableBase trait package-protected. For example, if your package is com.example.crud, you'll want to declare protected[crud] TableBase[T]...

Comment: See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291566/scala-using-companion-objects-parents-protected-methods/12303133#comment16508186_12291566) on the question regarding making TableBase package protected.